# Different order for getsockopt SO_PEERCRED in Linux and OpenBSD

Tags: linux, python, openbsd, unix-sockets

I'm trying to get the Unix socket peer credentials in python.

I am using this piece of code for that:

```
peercred = conn.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_PEERCRED, struct.calcsize("3i"))
pid, uid, gid = struct.unpack("3i", peercred)
```

This works correctly in Linux, but in OpenBSD the order is different.
In OpenBsd the order is `[uid, gid, pid]` instead.

What is causing this difference? How do I know when to use which order?

The linux systems I tried were running on a x86_64 architecture and the openbsd system was on a amd64 architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no python programmer, but I guess you should special case your code based on `sys.platform`.

`SO_PEERCRED` is not a standardized interface, and the actual structure / binary interface is different between the systems.

On Linux, as defined in `/usr/include/bits/socket.h`:

```
struct ucred {
        __u32   pid;
        __u32   uid;
        __u32   gid;
};
```

On OpenBSD, as defined in `/usr/include/sys/socket.h`:

```
struct sockpeercred {
        uid_t           uid;            /* effective user id */
        gid_t           gid;            /* effective group id */
        pid_t           pid;
};
```

(`uid_t`, `gid_t` and `pid_t` are also 32bit on OpenBSD)

Other systems (eg. solaris, FreeBSD) have a completely different interface -- for some code that gets the peer credentials in a "system-independent" manner you could look at the [update_client_creds()](https://github.com/heimdal/heimdal/blob/f0d9289d86e3f4081d096493853c182ca0efef38/lib/ipc/server.c#L499) function from the heimdal source code (which is using the `getpeereid(3)` library function on OpenBSD and FreeBSD instead of directly `SO_PEERCRED` or `LOCAL_PEERCRED`).

In any case, the credentials got this way will be those of the process that called `connect(2)` or `listen(2)` on the socket (a process that may no longer exist), not necessarily those of the process actually using the socket by writing to or reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cffi` and the "API level" approach.  This requires a C compiler, although it is possible to do the compiling on a compatible system and then re-use the result.

https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#api-mode-calling-the-c-standard-library

> Note that this works independently of the exact C layout of `struct passwd` (it is “API level”, as opposed to “ABI level”).